# Handling cold start for App Links for Facebook iOS SDK V4.1

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

This is implemented in AppDelegate

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

I have App Link with some parameters that is shared on Facebook. If my app is minimized, clicking link on Facebook opens my app and calling function

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

like it should happened.

**Problem** is if my app is terminated (not minimized) clicking link on Facebook opens my app but function is not called so I can't process input params.

I have found something about handling cold start in Facebook documentation but that info is outdated.

Did I miss something to implement or it is Facebook bug?

Comment: The only way for the Facebook app to open your app on iOS is by calling the openURL method, which should call your app delegate's openURL method, regardless of whether it's a cold start or just minimized.

Comment: @MingLi, but OpenURL method is not getting called when we we wrote as above in didfinishLaunch Method. it is always called didFinishLaunch method.

Comment: @NFilip Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I have done like @Nick Yap said but I forgot to post answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was boggling my head about this for a while...

When you open an app link and the app is not currently running, the app launches and first calls `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If you return `true` in this method, then it will follow by calling `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and passing in the proper parameters. However, if `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` returns `false`, then `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is never called.

If you are using the FBSDK, then you will be calling

```
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

at the end of your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If you look at their documentation, it states that it returns

> YES if the url was intended for the Facebook SDK, NO if not.

So, because YOUR applink is not intended for the FBSDK, it is returning `false`. However, the keys `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey` ARE available in your `launchOptions`. In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, if you call

```
if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL,
  sourceApplication = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String {      
   self.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil) 
}
```

then you can get around it. I'm not sure if you're supposed to be calling the AppDelegate methods manually, but it works for me.

Comment: is there is any solution?

Comment: `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`
`return true`
will this work?